# nginx is not writing logs in access log file

Tags: nginx

Nginx is not writing logs in access log file but error log is working fine. I have no clue that what happened, before access log was working fine. I remove access log file but still it's not writing log inside. Any idea what happened? any help will be appreciated. my nginx is running on windows 10.
here is my configuration file

```html
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  C:/nginx/log/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

your addressing schema is dedicated to linux environments not windows. you have to use the addressing schema associated with windows. use the code below instead.

```
access_log C://pathtoyourfile/access.log  main;
```

Comment: even this is not working.